# How to use yylval in flex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to build a lexical analyser with FLEX on windows.
I'm getting always an error:

> "undefined reference to `yylval'"

I declared yylval as a `extern` type up where all definitions are made as follows:

```
  %option noyywrap
    %{
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        #include "tokens.h"
        int nline = 1;
        int size_token_array = 100;
        int number_of_tokens_in_array = 0;
        int inc_token_array = 50;
        token *token_store ;
        extern yylval;

    %}
    delim [ \t]
    delim_nl [\n]
    ws {delim}+
    nl {delim_nl}+
    letter [a-z]
    digit [0-9]
    id {letter}(letter.digit)*
    int_num (0|([+-]?([1-9]{digit}*)))
    real_num [+-]?{digit}+(\.{digit}+)
    rel_op ">"|"<"|"<="|">="|"=="|"!="
    binary_ar_op "+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"="
    task_id {letter}(letter+digit)*
    signal_id {letter}(letter+digit)*

    %%
    "parbegin" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_PARBEGIN,yytext,nline); return 1;}
    "parend" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_PAREND,yytext,nline); return 1;}
    "task" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_TASK,yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "{" {create_and_store_token('{',yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "}" {create_and_store_token('}',yytext,nline); return 1;}
    "begin" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_BEGIN,yytext,nline); return 1;}  
    "end" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_END,yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "integer" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_INTEGER,yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "real" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_REAL,yytext,nline); return 1;}
    "||"  {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_PARALLEL,yytext,nline); return 1;}
    ";" {create_and_store_token(';',yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "," {create_and_store_token(',',yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "do" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_DO,yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "until" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_UNTIL,yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "od" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_OD,yytext,nline); return 1;}  
    "send" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_SEND,yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "accept" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_ACCEPT,yytext,nline); return 1;}  
    "(" {create_and_store_token('(',yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    ")" {create_and_store_token(')',yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    "<" {create_and_store_token(LT,yytext,nline); yylval=rel_op; return 1;} 
    ">" {create_and_store_token(GT,yytext,nline); yylval=rel_op; return 1;}  
    "<=" {create_and_store_token(LE,yytext,nline); yylval=rel_op; return 1;}  
    ">=" {create_and_store_token(GE,yytext,nline); yylval=rel_op; return 1;}  
    "==" {create_and_store_token(EQ,yytext,nline); yylval=rel_op; return 1;}  
    "!=" {create_and_store_token(NE,yytext,nline); yylval=rel_op; return 1;} 
    "*" {create_and_store_token('*',yytext,nline); yylval=binary_ar_op; return 1;}  
    "/" {create_and_store_token('/',yytext,nline); yylval=binary_ar_op; return 1;}  
    "+" {create_and_store_token('+',yytext,nline); yylval=binary_ar_op; return 1;}  
    "-" {create_and_store_token('-',yytext,nline); yylval=binary_ar_op; return 1;} 
    "=" {create_and_store_token('=',yytext,nline); yylval=binary_ar_op; return 1;} 
    {ws} ;
    {nl} nline++;
    id {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_ID,yytext,nline); return 1;} 
    int_num {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_INT_NUM,yytext,nline); return 1;}  
    real_num {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_REAL_NUM,yytext,nline); return 1;}  
    binary_ar_op {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_AR_OP,yytext,nline); return 1;}  
    "task_id" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_TASK_ID,yytext,nline); return 1;}  
    "signal_id" {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_SIGNAL_ID,yytext,nline); return 1;}  

    %%
    int main()
    {
        token_store = (token*)calloc(size_token_array,sizeof(token));
        free(token_store);
        return 0;

    }

    void create_and_store_token(int token_type,char* token_lexeme,int line_number){

        token new_token;
        new_token.ivalue = token_type;
        new_token.lexema = token_lexeme;
        new_token.line_number = line_number;

        if(size_token_array == (number_of_tokens_in_array-10)){

          token_store = (token*)realloc(token_store,inc_token_array*sizeof(token));
          size_token_array+=inc_token_array;
          number_of_tokens_in_array++;
          token_store[number_of_tokens_in_array]= new_token;

        }
        else{
          token_store[number_of_tokens_in_array]= new_token;
          number_of_tokens_in_array++;

        }
    }

    int nextToken(){
       return yylex();
    }

    void backToken(){
        token_store[number_of_tokens_in_array].ivalue = 0;
        token_store[number_of_tokens_in_array].lexema = "";
        token_store[number_of_tokens_in_array].line_number = 0;
        number_of_tokens_in_array--;
    }
```

Anybody have an idea how should I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`extern yylval;` means that `yylval` is defined somewhere else. So you have to do that.

Usually it is defined in the yacc/bison generated parser, so the name can be resolved when you link the scanner and the parser. If you aren't using bison/yacc, you will have to define `yylval` yourself. (If you actually need it. Your code does not give much of a hint what you need it for.)

By the way, your code has many other problems. One particularly glaring one is that you cannot use the value of the pointer `yytext` after the scanner moves on to the next token. If you need a persistent copy of the string pointed to by `yytext`, you need to make your own copy (and free the memory allocated for the copy when it is no longer needed.)

Also many of your regular expressions are incorrect. Macro uses ("definitions") must be surrounded​ by braces, so

```
id {create_and_store_token(TOKEN_ID,yytext,nline); return 1;}
```

won't match what you expect; it will only match the two-character the sequence <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>. Changing that to `{id}` is a start,
but the definition of `id` is also incorrect.

Personally, I avoid macros​ since they add no value to the code, IMO; they often create confusion. For example, your definition of `letter` only includes lower-case letters, something which would not at all be obvious to someone reading your code. It is much better to use Posix character classes, which don't require definitions and whose meanings are unambiguous: `[[: alpha:]]` for letters, `[[:lower:]]` for lower-case letters, `[[:alnum:]]` for letters or digits, etc.